# strptime() error message when trying to format variable

Tags: r

I've got a data frame with some date variables. I didn't create the date variables myself, they were in a csv file that I read in. The dates are in the %d/%m/%Y" format and are by default read in as factors.

I'd like to use those date variables to calculate some time spans, and would therefore like to be able to pass them into lubridate().

The problem is that when I attempt running some code to format the date variables, I get an error message that I don't understand. Any help would be much appreciated.

Current Code:

```
df$Var1 <- strptime(as.character(df$Var1), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Var", value = list(sec = numeric(0),  : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 10387
```

Comment: What do you get when typing strptime(as.character(df$Var1), "%d/%m/%Y")

Comment: Use `as.is=TRUE` in your `read.*` function to read them in as a character vector. Such an object is easier to work with.

Comment: For strptime(as.character(df$Var1), "%d/%m/%Y"), I get: character(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no rows in the dataframe you are trying to assign convert the Var1 column from.  Here is an example that reproduces your error.

```
mtcars_df = data.frame(mtcars)
df = data.frame(Var1=factor())
mtcars_df$Y =  strptime(as.character(df$Var1), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Validate that you are referencing the right data.frame in as.character(df$Var1), maybe you intended this to be `WhiteComplete$Var1`?

Comment: I've edited the code, it should have said df$Var1 <- strptime(as.character(df$Var1), "%d/%m/%Y"). But if WhiteComplete$Var1 <- strptime(as.character(df$Var1), "%d/%m/%Y"), would first setting WhiteComplete$Var1 <- NA take care of it?

Comment: Are you getting any different error now?  The reason for your first error is that you were trying to assign an empty value to a column of a data.frame that had 10387 rows.  Setting Var1 = NA would have introduced a column with all values of NA, but it still wouldn't prevent the error you were getting.

Comment: For, strptime(as.character(df$Var1), "%d/%m/%Y"), I get: character(0). But I don't get it, because when I do head(df$Var1) before running strptime(), I can see the entries.

Comment: What is the class of Var1, get this by running ```class(df$Var1)```?  Also, it would be helpful if you posted some example data.